# "papaja": "Author Note" heading placed at bottom of title page

Tags: r-markdown, papaja

When rendering my .Rmd file as a pdf the heading for "Author Note" is the last line of the cover page, with the text then starting on p2. Where do I go to insert a `\newpage` command? Or is there a better way to force the "author note to start on p. 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/crsh/papaja/issues/150#issuecomment-336874226) you could put it in the `note` field of the YAML front matter:

```yaml
note: "\newpage"
```

If you also have a note text try

```yaml
note: |
  This is my note.

  \newpage
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have a 'note' as well, so I can't use that part of the front matter to force the second page.

Comment: close: it needed only one slash: `\newpage` Thank you. Perhaps edit?